# How to create relations from 2 different tables to same column in 3rd table using EF code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 2 completely different tables with thousand rows of data:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentUserId { get; set; }
    // Fields for students
}

public class Teacher
{
    public Guid TeacherUserId { get; set; }
    // Fields for teachers
}

public class Player
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Extra Fields
    public Guid PlayerUserId { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }

    // Fields for Player no difference between teacher and student, JUST PLAYER
}
```

In the `Player` class, there's a field of type `Guid` that can store `StudentGuid` or `TeacherGuid`.

So I have to connect both `StudentUserId` and `TeacherUserId` to `PlayerUserId`.

So I created a map like this:

```
public class PlayerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
{
    public PlayerMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        //...

        HasRequired(x => x.Teacher)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PlayerUserId);
        HasRequired(x => x.Student)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PlayerUserId);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

if this relation is not correct, How can I handle this situation. I can't delete my data and I have to create 3rd table somehow keep previous data.

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a **field** - not a "filed" ...

Comment: Are you saying that you existing table of Players has one field `PlayerUserId` that is sometimes a foreign key to the `Students` table and sometimes to the `Teachers` table? How does the database know to which table the foreign key refers?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** have a single foreign key column that refers to one table some times, and to another table at other times.

If you have a situation like this, you need to have **two** separate foreign key fields - one for student, one for teacher - and make sure at most one of them is filled with a value at any given time.

```
public class Player
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key for "Teacher"
    public Guid? TeacherId { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key for "Student"
    public Guid? StudentId { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    // Fields for Player no difference between teacher and student, JUST PLAYER
}

public class PlayerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
{
    public PlayerMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        //...

        HasOptional(x => x.Teacher)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TeacherId);
        HasOptional(x => x.Student)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have one column as foreign key which is referring to two tables.

Though @Mark answer is answering your question. But you can have a different approach.

As you said that all the fields are same in both tables, so you can have only a single table, which will have a `type` field, it will tell you type whether its `Student` or `Teacher`. You can make `Id` and `Type` as composite primary key and refer in the other tables. So you can achieve whatever you want only using one column.